# .htaccess code to affect main domain only

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have two domains. 1) main 2) subdomain. This code in the .htaccess file is causing me problems.

```
# Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
# index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
# RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

As is, everything looks perfect on both sites and runs smoothly for the end user. However, this code means we can't make any admin changes on the main domain (page edits, creating content, etc).

If I "uncomment" the bottom 4 lines, I can make changes to the main domain, but the subdomain no longer points to the appropriate theme files.

Is it possible to "uncomment" the bottom 4 lines and have it only affect the main domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

To exclude the subdomain.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. You may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: I hit the check mark - such a stackoverflow noob. I think I did it right.

Comment: It's not nice to make fun of my English ;-)